# How to store a array of vue components and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

This is how the UI looks

[image: This is how the UI looks]

I have been working on the media mix (video editing) kinda project.
Every time a button is clicked a new clip (component) will be added to the array and I'm using `v-for` to display them on the left side, on the right side I have this clip Editor component, where we can add images, videos, texts, so what I want is to store these contents of each clip (image, text, videos) unique to them.

I'm storing these contents in an array, but what I want is I need to store these contents and be able to retrieve them, for example, if clip 1 is created and I add an image to it it should be stored, then if clip 2 is created the clip Editor on right should be empty and if I add a video to it it should also be stored, and if I click on clip 1 the stored image of the clip 1 should display, and then if I click clip 2 the video of clip 2 should display.

I have tried local storage it didn't work the new content is overriding the previous content, and I don't know how to use Vuex store.

I tried to save the contents array in local storage, and don't know how to use Vuex (i tried to learn but it's confusing and not working as well)

Comment: Did you tried pinia? It is created to be simpler than vuex

Comment: Bot for vuex and for pinia you will find plugins that will bound them with local storage. I suggest no handle it manually. check this: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/309